# select multiple values of record returned by function of plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

assume there is a function like

```
create function f (i int, out j int, out k int) as $$
begin
    j := i * i;
    k := i * i * i;
end
$$ language plpgsql
```

i need to use the result of f as below, but **missing FROM-clause** error raised

```
select id, a.j, a.k from (
    select t.id, f(t.id) a from table1 t) z
```

please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a join like this:

`select t.id, a.j, a.k from table1 t, f(t.id) a`

Comment: Just note - it will works on modern releases with LATERAL join support.